# Mechanism for incoming video call notification

Tags: android, vidyo

I have gone through the vidyo.io android SDK, would like to know about how to call a particular set of users and on those user sides, how will they get notified of incoming call.

Answer (score 0):

Vidyo.io doesn't have built-in API for direct calls, moreover for user management.
You should think about implementing all the user management on your backend. Then, use some real-time sync or notification service (like Firebase or Telegraph) for implementing incoming calls notifications.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to handle the call notifications provided by Vidyo.
However a preferable solution can be as follows-
1) You have to use socket to communicate with the server. On initiating the call you need to emit the socket with the name of participant with whom you are going to call.
2) Server will send a push notification (FCM can be used here) with some basic data like caller id , caller name, resource id (very important for vidyo) , then you need to silently handle the push notification to display the call ringing state.
3) And then you can connect with vidyo with the help of resource id.

Note: If you are using FCM then server need to send only data type notification to get the call in onReceive method in background and foreground.